# Socket timeout impact on performance

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I am using following configuration for MongoDB in my spring application:

socket Keep Alive=true
socket Time out=1500

My application is throwing socket time out exception while saving >=200000 records.But if keep socket timeout value as 15000 ms then it is working fine.
I want to know that if i keep socket timeout 60000 ms then is it going to impact application performance?

Answer (score 0):

The driver doesn't know whether there is no data being received on a connection because the server is working on fulfilling the query or because the connection died. If you set socket timeout to 1.5 seconds, you will receive timeout errors for all queries that take longer than 1.5 seconds to execute.

For this reason the drivers do not set a socket timeout by default.

If you set a socket timeout, you need to ensure it exceeds the execution time of queries you are issuing.

The drivers set up TCP keepalives to be notified when the connection times out on the network layer. You can reduce systemwide TCP keepalive intervals to detect dead connections quicker.